# PHP not getting first post value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Experts, my php is not showing the first value of the input field but console.log showing correctly

console.log

[image: Console.log]

PHP Output

[image: PHP Output]

```js
function summary() {
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    var date = $("#dddeliverydate").val();
    var soid = $("#sssoid option:selected").val();
    var form = $("#formsum").serialize();
    console.log(form);

    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: "&date=" + date + "&soid=" + soid + "&form=" + form,
      success: function (data) {
        var w = window.open("about:blank", "windowname");
        w.document.write(data);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

below is my PHP code

```php
<?php
for ($count = 0; $count < count($_POST['invoiceno']); $count++) {
    $data = array(
        $invoiceno = $_POST['invoiceno'][$count],
        $amount = $_POST['finalamount'][$count],
    );
    echo "Invoice NO " . $invoiceno . " Amount " . $amount . '<br>';
}
?>
```

what I am doing wrong need your help thanks in advance

Comment: It's easier if you just pass an object: `data: {date: '...', soid: '...', form: '...'}`

Comment: However, the ajax code you've posted doesn't seem to be related to the PHP code or the console log. They are using completely different parameters. In your ajax, you pass `date`, `soid` and `form` while you're using `invoiceno` and `finalAmount` in the PHP code and in the console log. Looks completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: can you please regenerate code for me I will really appreciate

Comment: Looking at the code again, it could be `form` that contains those params. If that's the case, you need to do `$_POST['form']['invoiceno']` and `$_POST['form']['finalamount']`. In your PHP code, do a `var_dump($_POST)` and check what it actually contains.

Comment: I am getting this



array(5) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2020-04-29" ["soid"]=> string(1) "2" ["form"]=> string(13) "invoiceno[]=1" ["finalamount"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "8208" [1]=> string(4) "3330" [2]=> string(3) "198" [3]=> string(1) "0" } ["invoiceno"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "7" } }

Comment: Suggestion, add the `dddeliverydate` and the `sssoid`-inputs to the `formsum`-form in your HTML. Then you can pass all data directly with just `data: $("#formsum").serialize()`. Then there won't be any need to manually build the string and your issues should be solved.

Comment: If you don't want to do that, then try changing: `"&date=" + date + "&soid=" + soid + "&form=" + form,` to be `"date=" + date + "&soid=" + soid + "&" + form,` (without `form=`).

Comment: Thank you so much @MagnusEriksson, problem resolved lots of respect

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code as below

```
function summary() {
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    var send_data= $("#formsum").serialize();
    send_data += '&date='+$("#dddeliverydate").val();
    send_data += '&soid ='+$("#sssoid option:selected").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: send_data,
      success: function (data) {
        var w = window.open("about:blank", "windowname");
        w.document.write(data);
      },
    });
  });
}
```